# Update custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I want to update a custom field value whenever an Editor visits a post.
I want to get it done to track hits on a post by editors on my site.
Not finding a proper solution or I am confused with multiple solutions.
I think I can use  `update_post_meta()` on single post page but not sure if it is a right solution.

Comment: I know, it's not a good solution or assistance, but with lack of time, I can say, you can take code-assist from ["Popular Posts" plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts) to track how to update db on user-view. Then try to narrow the broadness of the query with and `if()` condition with `current_user_can('editor')`. Hope that will light you to a good solution.

Comment: but i dont want to use any plugin for this functionality,it will be a theme feature

Comment: @Vicky he was suggesting you look at how that plugin does this, so that you may write your own solution, not use that plugin itself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do:

```
function track_editor_wpse_108606() {
  if (is_single()) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (user_can( $current_user, 'editor' )) {
      global $post;
      $current = get_post_meta($post->ID,'editor_tracker',true);
      $current = (!empty($current)) ? $current + 1 : 1; 
      update_post_meta($post->ID,'editor_tracker',$current);
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_head','track_editor_wpse_108606');
```

This is not especially efficient. You are reading and writing to the database for these page loads. [You could improve this by means of a direct SQL query](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2139/mysql_increment_an_exisitng_value/) if you want to go that somewhat risky route, and could improve it further by using Javascript to insert the value if you don't mind that it won't work if the user disables Javascript.